# Direct connection from XFINITY gateway with public IP

Tags: networking, router, modem

I would like to know if it is possible to create a direct connection from an XFINITY gateway (the router/modem combo) to a PC hooked up directly to the modem.

For example: so that it didn't give my IP a private IP address but a public one, and so I could renew my public IP address easily.

This was possible with my old DOCSIS 2.0 modem, but I want to know if it's possible with the XFINITY modem.

Comment: If only one PC is connecting to the router (and its hardwire ethernet, not wifi) you could ask comcast to put your modem/router in bridge mode.  Asking for that is hard tho, because the average call taker doesn't have a clue what you are talking about.  I've asked comcast for bridge mode before and succeeded in getting it done (in my case it was to avoid double NAT because I needed a specific router for a specific reason).

Comment: The better way is ditch the xfinity hardware and supply your own DOCSIS 3.0 modem, without a router.

Comment: @Tyson Awesome, thanks Tyson. Changed it in the router settings to enable bridge mode and now it is a public IP.

Comment: Nice you could get to the setting.  It used to be hidden from the customer on Comcast provided equipment

Comment: @Tyson You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Comcast provided modem/router, and you are only connecting one computer to it via a hardwired Ethernet connection (not wifi), then you may be able to log into the web interface for the device (try http://192.168.100.1) and see if you can find a setting for bridge mode.  If you can that's what you want to do, your computer will the obtain the public IP rather than a private IP.

If your Comcast provided equipment does not have a Bridge Mode setting, it is possible to get Comcast to set this for you.  I wouldn't take the 1-800 number as the route to request it tho, the calltakers usually have no concept of what you're asking for.  Instead use the [Comcast Support forum](http://forums.xfinity.com/) and PM one of the mods, or try twitter @ComcastCares

Not part of your question, but advise I'll give anyway:  If you have a Comcast owned internet modem or internet/phone device, stop paying the rental fee and buy your own.  The payback is 9 months to 2 years depending on your choices.  With phone service there are fewer choices, but the Arris combo units are available on amazon.  With no phone involved just buy a DOCSIS 3.0 (or 3.1) cable modem and if needed a separate router.  (I prefer separate devices because troubleshooting and upgrading over time are less complicated.)